# Getting DPI from an outlook application

Tags: .net, wpf, interop, office-interop, outlook-addin

I am making an outlook addin, and trying to place a window in the center of outlook.
in order to achieve that, I used to do the following:

```
Outlook.Application olApp;
...
dynamic activeWindow = olApp.ActiveWindow();
wpf_ui_control.Left = activeWindow.Left + (activeWindow.Width / 2) - (wpf_ui_control.Width / 2);
wpf_ui_control.Top = activeWindow.Top + (activeWindow.Height / 2) - (wpf_ui_control.Height / 2);
```

this of course, proved useless when DPI is not 100%.

I've seen a few examples getting DPI from different controls, but none from an outlook.explorer \ outlook.Inspect (the results of .ActiveWindow() ).

How will I go about getting the DPI, or calculating the center in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918877/how-can-i-get-the-dpi-in-wpf

Comment: I actually canceled the first answer due to not actually having a visible control yet, but there is another solution there exactly for this occasion. going to check it out!

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier this solution did help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution was actually suggested here:
[How can I get the DPI in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918877/how-can-i-get-the-dpi-in-wpf)

```
var dpiXProperty = typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("DpiX", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var dpiYProperty = typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("Dpi", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

var dpiX = (int)dpiXProperty.GetValue(null, null);
var dpiY = (int)dpiYProperty.GetValue(null, null);
```